# HTML 5 logo is out what it really means?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working/learning HTML5 since couple of months and HTML 5 logo is out couple of days back. What it really means for different people like Developer, Users and Enterprises ?

[image]

Comment: It's a logo. It means nothing more than it was "designed" to mean: See http://www.w3.org/QA/2011/01/an_html5_logo.html for "the source". No reason to read anything special into it.

Comment: http://marcovhv.tumblr.com/post/2911242584/html5-logo-by-the-oatmeal-is-way-better-than-the

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means you can now put an ugly logo onto pages that don't work with IE8...

(Developer perspective)

Comment: On the second thought: It's good for Google Chrome though, now you can link with a compatibility icon: www.google.com/chrome